# for to next loop every word the first letter will be capital

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

what will i do to make it accept my equation and able to make all inserted word first letter capital? i f5 this equation and it show some yellow errors if i input a word. 
 i tried if i = 0 then 
so it only shows first word first letter capital the rest isnt.

[https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=209840356412510&id=100021596419779&refid=17&**tn**=%2AW-R&_rdr](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=209840356412510&id=100021596419779&refid=17&__tn__=%2AW-R&_rdr)

Comment: Don't post links to images, post your code here. Also mention the issue with your approach,what you expected and what happened instead?

Comment: sorry its just i cant insert pictures and im only using mobile. so i cant do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your code on your post so i don't know what you tried but this code works perfectly in order to achieve your goal.

```
Dim textBoxString As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim
'Create a string array with every words'
Dim words() As String = textBoxString.Split(" ") 
'labelString is our final result'
Dim labelString As String = ""
'cycle throught every word'
For i = 0 To textBoxString.Length - 1
    Try
        'substring(0,1) takes only the first char of the word'
        words(i) = words(i).ToUpper().Substring(0, 1) & words(i).Substring(1, words(i).Length - 1)
        labelString = labelString & words(i) & " "
    Catch ex As Exception
        Err.Clear()
        Exit For
    End Try
Next
Label1.Text = labelString
```

**Little explanation of my code**

```
words(i).ToUpper.Substring(0,1)
```

it takes only the first char of every word throught the cycle.

```
words(i).Substring(1, words(i).Lenght -1)
```

it takes the entire word without the first char

```
labelString = labelString & words(i) & " "
```

it concatenates every words back together.

Comment: well sir i have a link on facebook xD i used for to next loop and string function only the basic version.

Comment: can you just try only the string function and for loop? if only you could see my solution.

Comment: TY FOR THE ANSWER so much appreciated ill try to study those codes of yours

Comment: Sorry rookie i had alot of truble yesterday. I'm at work at the moment and links like fb are disabled. I will appreciate if you'll edit your post by adding your code.

Comment: @Rookieone I edited my answer in order to explain better my code

Comment: thank you so much simo but can you try using if statement there? i mean inside the for loop you will use if statement? i still dont know that try statement

Comment: because when i tried it `Dim words() as String` creates an array of 14 elements, most of them are unused. I'm lazy and I wasn't feeling to find a better solution insted of just use a try/catch statement. Without it the code throws an exception